# Slither not importing the required files

Tags: node.js, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, consensys-truffle

I have this smart contract called Party.sol

```
    pragma solidity 0.8.17;

    import "../tokens/IERC721.sol";

    import "./PartyGovernanceNFT.sol";
    import "./PartyGovernance.sol";
```

I'm trying to extract the call graph using slither :

```
    slither Party.sol --print call-graph
```

I get this error :

```
   crytic_compile.platform.exceptions.InvalidCompilation: Invalid solc compilation Error: Source "tokens/IERC721.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
  --> Party.sol:4:1:
     |
     | import "../tokens/IERC721.sol";
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there any configuration I need to do to the compiler or slither in order to read correctly the imports?

I got exctly what I expected, I putted a description and code and got out what I looked for

Answer (score 0):

When encountering the error while analyzing the `Party.sol` smart contract with slither, it is essential to verify that the `IERC721.sol` file is located in the correct directory relative to `Party.sol`.

Double-checking the import statement's relative path is also crucial, as `../tokens/IERC721.sol` suggests that the `IERC721.sol` file should be in a directory one level above the location of `Party.sol` Ensuring the accurate placement of files and correct import paths should usually resolve the issue.

If needed, consider using the full absolute path or configuring slither to include the correct path to the "tokens" directory.

If the error persists, it might be helpful to explore [crytic-compile](https://github.com/crytic/crytic-compile) library documentation for additional insights on compiling contracts.

Comment: Yes the relative import path is good!
Do you know how to configure the way slither is conccidering the paths?